# Call method when app enters foreground from a dead state

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to call a method in my iOS app only when I enter in it from a dead state, meaning that the app isn't running in the background. I have searched for it and I came up with the method:

```
applicationWillEnterForeground:
```

But when I put some prints inside this method in my app delegate, the prints are not called at any time. Specifically what I want to do is to call a service to check wether the user's token access is valid or not, so I would show him the Log In view or the home view.

Answer (score 0):

The app delegate method you're asking for is:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool
```

This is called when the app finishes launching, which occurs when it was previously not in a background or suspended state.

That said, for your use case, I'd put this in:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication)
```

This gets called anytime the app enters the foreground which is more appropriate for this problem. If it's not being called (as you suggest), I expect that you haven't declared the method correctly (declare it exactly as above), or you haven't declared it on the UIApplicationDelegate.

For full details, including how to handle the new scene delegates in iOS 13+ (which are different, and tied to the UISceneDelegate), see [Managing Your App's Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle).